# How can i get all records from joining two table which have 2 different records for joining key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 2 tables

Table 1:

```
Name   quality   identifier   views   visits   date           mmmyy
P1     high       jbjs         64      7         1-1-2020     Jan20
P2     high2      jbjs         3       0         1-2-2020     Jan20
```

Table 2:

```
email  Qty_sent identifier   click   date           mmmyy
E1     2000      jbjs         45      1-23-2020     Jan20
E2     1000      jbjs         9       1-4-2020      Jan20
```

what I am doing is

```
select a.*, b.* from table1 a
inner join table2 b 
on a.identifier=b.identifier 
and a.mmmyy=b.mmmyy
```

what I expect to get is

```
Name   quality   identifier   views   visits   date           mmmyy    email  Qty_sent identifier   click   date           mmmyy
P1     high       jbjs         64      7         1-1-2020     Jan20    E1     2000      jbjs         45      1-23-2020     Jan20
P2     high2      jbjs         3       0         1-2-2020     Jan20   E1     2000      jbjs         45      1-23-2020     Jan20
P1     high       jbjs         64      7         1-1-2020     Jan20   E2     1000      jbjs         9       1-4-2020      Jan20
P2     high2      jbjs         3       0         1-2-2020     Jan20   E2     1000      jbjs         9       1-4-2020      Jan20
```

Comment: Do a CROSS join: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all rows the first table combined against all rows from the second table, that's called a CROSS JOIN.

You can type it as:

```
select *
from table1
cross join table2
```